# How to pause or wait in the mocha test case -- setTimeout not working

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, settimeout, mocha.js

I built a `selenium-mocha` test case that will open google, enter some text and then click search.  But I need to perform the search 60 seconds after the search text has been entered.

**Test case code snippet:**

```
var assert = require('assert'),
    test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing'),
    webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var urladd ='http://www.google.com/';

function clickLink(link){
    link.click();
    return link;
}

var testSimple=function(searchContent){
    var browser = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();

    test.describe('\n\nGoogle Search\n', function() {
        this.timeout(60000);
        test.it('Enter element to be searched', function(done) {
            browser.get(urladd);
            browser.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys(searchContent);
            browser.getTitle().then(function(title) {
                assert.equal(title,'Google');
            })
        });

        test.it('Click search button', function(done) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                browser.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).then(clickLink).then(function(){
                    browser.getTitle().then(function(title) {
                        assert.equal(title,'selenium mocha test cases - Google Search');
                    });
                });
            },30000);
        });
    });
}

testSimple('selenium mocha test cases');
```

I used `setTimeout` to pause for 60 seconds, but mocha just passes the test case without executing the code inside the timeout.

**Console output:**

```
Google Search

  √ Enter element to be searched (7771ms)
  √ Click search button

2 passing (8s)
```

Can anyone can suggest a better solution for this (or any other APIs that could be used for pausing the mocha test)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of notes before getting to the meat of the matter:

1. You don't need `done` for the functions that you pass to `test.it`. You are using `selenium-webdriver` wrapped Mocha functions, which make it so that all your tests are asynchronous. So `done` is useless.
2. Your second test is dependent on the first. That's bad design. Tests should be independent. (There are already questions on SO that address how to make tests independent so I'm not going to address this again here.)

As for your wait issue, here is how you can solve it. You can modify your second test to be like this:

```
test.it('Click search button', function() {
    var flow = webdriver.promise.controlFlow();
    flow.execute(
        function () { return webdriver.promise.delayed(30 * 1000); });
    browser.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).then(clickLink);
    browser.wait(function () {
        return browser.getTitle().then(function (title) {
            return title === 'selenium mocha test cases - Google Search';
        });
    });
});
```

This creates a [control flow](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Control_Flows) in which a promise is executed.  (`webdriver.promise.delayed` just creates a [promise](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Promises) that will be resolved in the number of miliseconds passed to the function.)

Then you can just call methods on `browser`. The net effect is pausing the operations on the browser for 30 seconds.

An additional issue with your code is that it was not *waiting* for the title to change. When the click happens, it takes a bit for the title to change, so the Selenium code has to wait (hence the `browser.wait` call at the end.) If the title never changes the test will fail with a timeout.

Comment: Thank you so much Louis,But the rest of the code were not executed sequentially

Comment: Glad to help, but I don't understand what you mean by "but the rest of the code were not executed sequentially."

Comment: The getTitle() gets executed before the click event

Comment: Not at all. I've just added some debugging instruction to my code and the click *definitely* happens *before* the title check. The problem is that you do not use `browser.wait` in your code to wait until the title changes (and I did not correct *this* problem, because that was not the topic of your question). There's a delay between the click and the change of title and your code executes too fast.

Comment: Yeah its working fine.Thank you some much.Louis I have been facing this issue for a month, to keep the test case wait.Thanks for your help